# WSO2 LDAP Authentication Issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am having some issues with ldap user authentication with wso2 Identity Server ( 5.7.0 ) server. I am able to configure the ldap server and I am able to list the users from ldap server as well as list the "user profile" for the users. When try to login as same ldap user it fails and returning the below error in the logs. I have given full permission to the user.

```
[2019-12-03 11:42:10,716]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG}-  Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-Claim-Values Target=LDAP-NEW/user1 Data={"Claims":{},"Profile":"default"} Outcome=Success
[2019-12-03 11:42:11,968]  WARN {AUDIT_LOG}-  Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Authentication Target=LDAP-NEW/user1 Data=null Outcome=Failure Error={"Error Message":"Un-expected error while authenticating","Error Code":"31001"}
[2019-12-03 11:42:11,989]  WARN {AUDIT_LOG}-  Failed Administrator login attempt 'user1[-1234]' at [2019-12-03 11:42:11,988+0530]
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the error log during the failed authentication? You can get it from wso2carbon.log file

Comment: Hello  senthalan, I am getting the same error above mentioned while user login. I have configured one openldap server and able to login from that, but the issue is with our enterprise cooperate ldap server.

Comment: Did you configured  the "UserNameAttribute" and "UserSearchBase" correctly as per your cooperate LDAP server?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify your administrator login using **ldapwhoami** command line

```
ldapwhoami -h localhost -p 389 -D "[Connection Name]" -w [Connection Password]
```

Add -x parameter if you are using OpenLDAP simple mode authentication